# What fuel injectors I have to install?

Tags: emissions, mazda-3, fuel-injectors

Recently the fuel injectors of my Mazda 3 SP5 2006 2.3L stop working, they still works, but my mechanic said that are in bad conditions. Anyway, when I search the fuel injectors for my car, I found two of them ( L3G5-13-250 and LF62-13-250). The first is for the federal emission standard and the other for the California emission standard.  I think that my car have the federal emission standard. Can I buy the one with the California emission standard? This one (California) is $66 and the other (federal) in $136.  Is a big difference in the price. 
I read that the California emission standard is more strict than the federal.

Will either injector work for my car?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing the proposed duplicate is for a Honda Accord. Same question, but different vehicle.

Comment: @Zaid the basic idea of the question is the same - the difference between California emission standard and Federal emission standard injectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the California emissions injectors flow more fuel and have a higher resistance. The design also looks different this could lead to fuel leaks. If you had a Federal emissions car it could also throw off the engine computer either resulting in running too rich or the car setting a circuit code.

Answer (score 3):

Your car is either a California car or it is not.

You can call the dealer and give them your VIN number and in order to have your vehicle identified.  Once you know what your car is then you can purchase the proper fuel injector that is required for your vehicle rather than hoping that the cheap injector will work.

Comment: There should also be a under hood sticker with California or Federal emissions labels.

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't have my car at the moment. Anyway, I decided to call a local Mazda autoparts and they sold me the original federal emission fuel injectors for $105 c/u. So, I think that isn't a bad price. I will mount the injectors this Friday ;)